# error when flask app with chatter bot hosted with a wsgi script [sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file]

Tags: python-3.x, flask, chatterbot

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 server and I have created a flask application and hosted using apache_wsgi script.
Individually.
my python file as follows

`` chatbot = ChatBot(
    'Dan',
    storage_adapter="chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter"
)
chatbot.set_trainer(ChatterBotCorpusTrainer)
chatbot.train(`
    `"chatterbot.corpus.english.greetings"
)
def chat(text):
    response = chatbot.get_response(text)
    if response.confidence >= 0.8:
        return response
   else:
       pass ``

when I run it individually it's running but when I use the flask app it's giving an error.

I have put the error log

`[client 71.6.232.4:41358] sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution for this. There are two major solutions to this problem.

1. Give the permission for the file `sudo chomd -R 777 db.sqlite3`
2. Give the apache_wsgi to execute as the current ubuntu username
       user=name use following [reference](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html)